# How to search number full size japanese in couchbase

Tags: full-text-search, couchbase, cjk

I'm getting error when try full text search number full size "９" in couchbase 6.0.3. Exception throws : err: bleve: QueryBleve validating request, err: parse error: error parsing number: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing.

If i searching with some string "９abc" , searching successfull so i think  , lib of couchbase search regconize "９" is number and parse failed. I dont know to to resolve problem. Please help me!

Couchbase 6.0.3

```
ConjunctionQuery fts = SearchQuery.conjuncts(SearchQuery.queryString(source));
fts = fts.and(SearchQuery.matchPhrase("123").field("tm"));
fts = fts.and(SearchQuery.booleanField(true).field("active"));

SearchQuery query = new SearchQuery("segmentIndex"), fts);
SearchQueryResult result = bucket.query(query);
```

Exception throws : err: bleve: QueryBleve validating request, err: parse error: error parsing number: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing.

Comment: What do you mean by "Number full size japanese"?

Comment: I could not reproduce it, could you please add more details?

Comment: text when i search error "９" (UTF-16 format is \uff19) . My full text index in  below comment

Comment: Could you please also add an example of how your data looks like?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 "name": "tmSegmentIndex",
 "type": "fulltext-index",
 "params": {
  "doc_config": {
   "docid_prefix_delim": "",
   "docid_regexp": "",
   "mode": "type_field",
   "type_field": "type"
  },
  "mapping": {
   "analysis": {
    "analyzers": {
     "remove_fullsize_number": {
      "char_filters": [
       "remove_fullsize_number"
      ],
      "token_filters": [
       "cjk_bigram",
       "cjk_width"
      ],
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "type": "custom"
     }
    },
    "char_filters": {
     "remove_fullsize_number": {
      "regexp": "９",
      "replace": "9",
      "type": "regexp"
     }
    }
   },
   "default_analyzer": "cjk",
   "default_datetime_parser": "dateTimeOptional",
   "default_field": "_all",
   "default_mapping": {
    "default_analyzer": "cjk",
    "dynamic": true,
    "enabled": true
   },
   "default_type": "_default",
   "docvalues_dynamic": true,
   "index_dynamic": true,
   "store_dynamic": false,
   "type_field": "_type"
  },
  "store": {
   "indexType": "scorch",
   "kvStoreName": "mossStore"
  }
 },
 "sourceType": "couchbase",
 "sourceName": "tm-segment",
 "sourceUUID": "973fdbffc567cdfe8f423289b9700f19",
 "sourceParams": {},
 "planParams": {
  "maxPartitionsPerPIndex": 171,
  "numReplicas": 0
 },
 "uuid": "1265a6bedbfd027c"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can you just try a custom analyser with an asciifolding character filter like below.

Also, when you directly search from the UI box without a field name, its getting searched in the "_all" field which won't get the right/intended analyser used for parsing the query text.

You may field scope the query there like => field:"９"

```
{
  "type": "fulltext-index",
  "name": "FTS",
  "uuid": "401ee8132818cee3",
  "sourceType": "couchbase",
  "sourceName": "sample",
  "sourceUUID": "6bd6d0b1c714fcd7697a349ff8166bf8",
  "planParams": {
    "maxPartitionsPerPIndex": 171,
    "indexPartitions": 6
  },
  "params": {
    "doc_config": {
      "docid_prefix_delim": "",
      "docid_regexp": "",
      "mode": "type_field",
      "type_field": "type"
    },
    "mapping": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzers": {
          "custom": {
            "char_filters": [
              "asciifolding"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "unicode",
            "type": "custom"
          }
        }
      },
      "default_analyzer": "standard",
      "default_datetime_parser": "dateTimeOptional",
      "default_field": "_all",
      "default_mapping": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "dynamic": false,
            "enabled": true,
            "fields": [
              {
                "analyzer": "custom",
                "docvalues": true,
                "include_in_all": true,
                "include_term_vectors": true,
                "index": true,
                "name": "id",
                "type": "text"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "default_type": "_default",
      "docvalues_dynamic": true,
      "index_dynamic": true,
      "store_dynamic": false,
      "type_field": "_type"
    },
    "store": {
      "indexType": "scorch"
    }
  },
  "sourceParams": {}
}
```

Asciifolding filters are a part of 6.5.0 Couchbase release. Its available in beta for trials.